# Magento CE 2.3.5 Web Setup Wizard

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-upgrade

I am using the Magento 2.3.4-p2(CE).

In Admin Panel, System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard redirect to the following url

> Url: BASE_URL/setup/index.php/session/unlogin

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Comment: you want to magento-upgrade so you are use command line.

Comment: It doesn't work for me

Comment: what's problem in command line upgrade???